# How to programmatically set Fiddler Win8 Loopback Exemptions?

Tags: fiddler, firewall, traffic, loopback, appx

We need to ensure that fiddler is exempting all apps for every build.

[image]

What we’re noticing is after  we do the initial exempt all, and after a couple of builds, our tests fail because some apps are no longer exempted.

We want a programmatic way to check and set the exemptions before each test run to ensure all apps are included.

I’ve searched the registry and it appears that its not using a configuration file.

Has anyone, ever, been able to programmatically set fiddler exemptions?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is posted here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx

Get installed packages:

```
get-appxpackage | ?{$_.PackageFamilyName -like '*<filter>*'} | select packagefamilyname
```

Adds an exemptions for the package:

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –a –n=<PackageFamilyName>
```

Deletes an exemption for the package:

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –d –n=<PackageFamilyName>
```

Answer (score 1):

`EnableLoopback.exe` is a command-line utility included with Fiddler.

Simply run it with the `-all` command-line argument to automatically exempt all application packages. Alternatively, `CTRL+Click` the `WinConfig` button in the Fiddler toolbar (which simply runs `enableloopback.exe -all` itself).

Comment: How do you tell fiddler to go back to the default?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the default". You can simply open the tool and Exempt None if you like.